# Best BaaS for iOS poll app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloud, backend, mbaas

I am making iOS poll App, each device is able to make one vote per month.

When vote is made on iOS app, following is send to BaaS (UDID, vote, local_timestemp)
Then BaaS need to check that this UDID has not voted this month already:

- if it has voted, than return "NO" to iOS device
- if it has not voted in this month:

  - then return local_timestemp to iOS device
  - save (UDID, vote, local_timestemp) to DB

There is also view controller for showing current votes from all devices.
This will be polled every N seconds/minutes, so that new votes are updated.
This should return number of votes for each option, like is there are two options than return {1: 500, 2: 340}, this mean option one have 500 votes and option two have 340 votes.

I am also have question regarding how to get current votes from all devices ?
Is it better to compute number of votes for each option every time when they are requested.
Or should I use counter when new vote is updated, here I see problem of synchronization.
Or justy to update counter every N second/minutes ?

I am looking for BaaS that provide service for these features.
I have not preference for any BaaS provider.
But BaaS need to provide ability to run custom bushes logic, for this poll app to work.

Answer (score 1):

Parse.com is one of the best to help you in your case.
You can also run Cloud Code, and Jobs each N minutes.
Their documentation is pretty much straightforward and simple. And it's for free! https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS

Comment: Facebook is closing Parse service.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Parse has shut down. Why don't you try out [Hasura](http://www.hasura.io) instead. It should prove to fit your needs. Check out [compare](http://compare.beta.hasura.io) to see how Hasura compares with other providers and also, [explore](http://explore.beta.hasura.io) to check out everything that is possible with Hasura (you will end up with a blog web app as well as a todo web app deployed live in under 15 mins).

Hasura has a lot of advantages over other providers as it lets you own your own data and infrastructure, you can also write your custom code in the language of your own choosing.